# Inconsistent crashes on Heroku app: where to look?

Tags: heroku, crash

**Disclaimer:** Please tell me if the question is too broad, and I will do my best to narrow it down.

We have an Heroku app which is running 2 web 1X dynos. This infrastructure has been running for the last 9 months.

However, in the last few weeks, we had several episodes where the app would see its response times skyrocketing for about an hour, before returning to normal without us doing anything about it.

On the pictures below, you can find an extract of Heroku Metrics during one of these "episodes", which happened yesterday afternoon.

[image: report1]
[image: report2]

As you can see, response time is going up and eventually, almost any request made to the server gets a timeout. During the event, it was barely possible to even load the home page of our website, hosted on this app. Most of the times, we would get the "Application Error" Heroku page.

**What I see is:**

- The amount of requests to the server (failed or not) was not crazily high (less than 1000 every 10 minutes). For this reason, I think a DDOS attack is out of the picture.
- Everything that is shown by Heroku Logs is that the failed request get a 503 (Service Unavailable) error, which would make me think about an overload.
- The dynos do not seem overloaded. The memory usage is low, and the dyno load is reasonable, nothing unusual.
- Heroku reported no issue during our crash event, as https://status.heroku.com/ states (last incident was on the 1st of July).

Restarting the dynos through several methods (from the interface, a command line or triggering an automatic deployment via our Gitlab repository) had no effect.

I am quite unsure as to how to interpretate these metrics, and what would be the solution to ensure this kind of episode does not happen again.
So my question is: **where should I look?** Is there some kind of documentation about how to investigate crashes on Heroku apps?

Comment: "where should I look?"—I'd start with your application logs, e.g. via `heroku logs`.

Comment: @Chris I edited my post. Heroku logs are showing nothing but 503 errors on the scripts that don't load, which would suggest an overload.